# How do I now read an element of that XML into a variable

Tags: arrays, xml, azure-data-factory

How do I now read an element of that XML into a variable
I am trying to read data from an API with Azure Data Factory. First I need to call a login method, which provides an XML response. I need to take an element from that XML and put it into my next API call to get the data that I need.

Currently, I am using the Copy data tool to call the login method and save the XML to data lake storage. How do I now read an element of that XML into a variable?

If there is a better way of doing this then please advise, but I would still like to know how to read an XML element into a variable.
I need to pass sp id,mac_add,interface as a input to call next api while will load other file in json format

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<anp:anp_sp_list xmlns:anp="http://www.soap.com" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.soap.com anp_sp_list.xsd">
  <sp id="5152">
  <controller_id>107</controller_id>
  <folder id="1">Top</folder>
  <group id="7">Cisco AP</group>
  <mac_add>45:2B:01:DB:FA:S6</mac_add>
  <mfgr>Cisco</mfgr>
  <model id="264">WEN</model>
    <id index="1">
     <antenna />
     <antenna_gain />
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <operational_mode>n</operational_mode>
     <interface>0</interface>
    </id>
    <id index="2">
     <antenna />
     <antenna_gain />
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <operational_mode>N</operational_mode>
     <interface>1</interface>
     </id>
     <id index="3">
     <antenna />
     <antenna_gain />
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <operational_mode>n</operational_mode>
     <interface>2</interface>
  </id>
 </sp>
   <sp id="5251">
  <controller_id>07</controller_id>
  <folder id="1">Top</folder>
  <group id="7">AP</group>
  <mac_add>99:2B:01:DB:AF:S6</mac_add>
  <mfgr>sco</mfgr>
  <model id="264">WEN</model>
  <id index="3">
     <antenna />
     <antenna_gain />
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <operational_mode>n</operational_mode>
     <interface>1</interface>
  </id>
  <id index="5">
     <antenna />
     <antenna_gain />
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <operational_mode>N</operational_mode>
     <interface>4</interface>
  </id>
  <id index="3">
     <antenna />
     <antenna_gain />
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <operational_mode>n</operational_mode>
     <interface>8</interface>
  </id>
 </sp>
</anp:anp_sp_list>
```

Comment: Hi @heenashaikh, you have not actually posted your sample XML.  Please post it and some expected results, plus what you have tried.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, that is not valid xml.  Please post a valid piece of XML and edit your original post, rather than place it in the comments.

Comment: It is possible to query XML items into variables using Data Factory, eg with the Set Variable task.  However your XML has many sp ids, (5152, 5252) and each of those has many ids (which has the interface attribute).  So I think you need to be a bit clearer about your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to query values from XML in core Azure Data Factory (ADF) using the usual dot and array syntax.  In my simple example, I have a file in the datalake which I load up into the pipeline with a lookup.  I then get the values from the xml using the following expressions:

**Set variable spId**

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['anp:anp_sp_list'].sp[0]['@id'])
```

**Set variable varMac**

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['anp:anp_sp_list'].sp[0].mac_add)
```

**Set variable varInterface**

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['anp:anp_sp_list'].sp[0].id[0].interface)
```

[image]

This works for simple xml.  Here I am getting the first `sp` element and the first `interface` element using the `[0]` syntax.  Note the `@` syntax for the xml attributes.  The problem is your sample XML has multiple `sp` attributes and they in turn have multiple `id` elements (which house the `interface` elements), so I think you need to be a bit clearer with your expected results.  It would be possible to use a `For Each` activity to loop through the multiple `sp` elements, but you would need a child package to loop through the inner ids again.  You might be better off just converting the xml to a flat .csv and using that in a lookup.

If it is too complicated to do in ADF, you could pass the problem off to some other compute, eg Azure SQL DB is quite capable with XML, or use Databricks Notebooks or even Mapping Data Flows for a low-code experience.  A simple example in Azure SQL DB using its built-in XML capabilities:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://www.soap.com' AS anp )
SELECT
    sp.c.value('(@id)[1]', 'INT') spId,
    sp.c.value('(mac_add)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') mac_add,
    id.c.value('(@index)[1]', 'INT') idIndex,
    id.c.value('(interface)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') interface
FROM @xml.nodes('anp:anp_sp_list/sp') sp(c)
    CROSS APPLY sp.c.nodes('id') id(c)
ORDER BY spId, idIndex;
```

My results:

[image]

If you are planning to use a For Each activity, you can pass the following expression to the Settings > Items section:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['anp:anp_sp_list'].sp
```

Obviously adjust the activity name for your requirements.  This will then allow you to access the XML using similar expressions to above, eg

```
@string(item()['@id'])

@string(item().mac_add)
```

Comment: Indeed ! but what if we want to pass array(sp[]) to for each loop for complex xml file

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with a For Each activity example.  Can you please upvote / mark as answer if it proves useful to you?

Comment: This is a separate question.  Please raise a separate question and I’m sure someone will be able to help you.  If the answer above has been useful, please upvote it and/or mark it as the answer.